# Crashlytics/Answers: Is it possible to get programatically last x events collected by Answers?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric-answers

In iOS App (objective C) I'm using Fabrics Crashlytics features.

- Custom Logging [CLS_LOG ...]
- Custom Keys
- and Answers for events logging.

Everything works as expected.

What I want to achieve is to be able to send last x events let's say through e-mail from user in the case of some unexpected behaviour.

If there is some strange behaviour (not crash) I would like, that user is able send us last x events which lead to this situation.

Of course I can implement some custom events logging, but I was thinking of using Fabric Answers events logging mechanism, when is already implemented in the app.

Is it possible ? Or what would be the best approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. We don't have a mechanism in our SDK that would enable sending of the last x events in this situation.

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for answer. I don't need to have the functionality to send last x events. I'm looking for the functionality to get in the App (code) somehow last x events. Something like "[Answers getLastXEvents]". Or something similar ...

Comment: That's not something we offer either.